# When i try to build my android studio project: Gives me below error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[Here I have attached the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZeKc.png) 
Please see that,  This error occurs after I add firebase to my app.

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;

Comment: do you use support-annotations ?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild project ?

Comment: clean and rebuild project, but no luck

Comment: I have answered your question, can you check below

Comment: no it not worked :(

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issues while working with Google Play Services, to fix this kindly follow the below method.

Just parse the below code from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

To:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```